Repairing a Rotted Post: Concrete Pouring Challenges with Two Approaches
I'm dealing with a challenging post repair situation and need expert advice. Here's my scenario:

I have a substantial wooden post (18x18cm or about 7x7 inches) supporting a roof.
The post is rotted at the base and this part needs to be cut.
I can't remove the post entirely or lift the roof due to attached windows.
I'm using temporary supports to hold the roof while working on the post.


I've considered two approaches and I'm unsure which is best or if there's a better solution:
Approach 1: Using a Post Base Plate

Cut off the rotted part of the post.
Treat the bottom of the remaining post with tar for protection.
Attach a post base plate (PPA100) to the bottom of the post.



Pour concrete to meet the level of the hanging base plate.

Approach 2: Direct Concrete to Rubber Pad

Cut off the rotted part of the post.
Attach (glue?) a rubber pad to the bottom of the post for protection.
Pour concrete directly up to this rubber pad.

My main concerns:

How to ensure the concrete stops exactly at the right level (either the base plate or the rubber pad)?
How to account for concrete shrinkage, especially in Approach 2?
How to ensure good contact between the cured concrete and the base plate or rubber pad?

Questions:

Which approach seems more feasible and cost-effective, and why?
How do professionals handle pouring concrete to an exact height in situations like these, using affordable methods?
What's the best way to minimize and account for concrete shrinkage without increasing costs significantly?
Are there any specific techniques to ensure a good bond between the
new concrete and the base plate or rubber pad that don't require
expensive materials?
Is there a better, more economical approach I haven't considered?

I initially favored Approach 2 but became concerned about achieving the exact height with concrete shrinkage. Now I'm considering Approach 1, but I'm open to all suggestions, especially those that are budget-friendly.
Any advice or tips for cost-effective solutions from those who've dealt with similar situations would be greatly appreciated. I'm working with a limited budget, so the most affordable yet reliable methods are preferred.
Thanks in advance!

With respect, the structure looks like it is suffering from a great amount of neglect.  The post needs replacing, but there are a number of other issues as well.   I would not subscribe to either of your solutions.  I think an evaluation by an engineer may be in order. Especially if you expect to reside in the structure.

@RMDman Yes sadly, the whole property suffered a great amount of neglect. Nobody reside on the structure. I don't own it. It's a complicated situation, to make it short, without a cheap simple fix, it will simply fall down.

If it doesn't need to look pretty or last for ever, I'd be inclined to get a pair of pressure-treated 2x8 boards (38mm x 184mm in the UK ?) long enough to reach from almost ground-level to to the roof, and position one on each side of the corner. Then 2 or 3 bolts into the concrete for each of them, and a sufficiency of nice long 4-5" screws spread all the way up each board.

I did not thought about sandwiching the existing pillar between two long pressure-treated boards bolted to the concrete at the bottom and screwed into the pillar all the way up. That's interesting. Do you think the board would be able to support the weight of the roof?

@brhans might as well cut out the rotted bottom of the post and fill it with another piece while you're at it.
